# Multi changeable areas of a image on a iPhone

Tags: iphone, image, titanium, mask, appcelerator-mobile

I have an image with picture of a person and I want to let the user to pick some area of the person and change the color. But how can I best create a multi-mask image?
E.g. should the user be able the change the color for a leg or a hand.

I am using Titanium Appcelerator, and right now I had a solution with buttons placed over the image, which is not a pretty and accepted solution.

The Kitchensink example, has only one area which can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found for working with sections of an image is to divide the image into different views then use a vertical or horizontal view to glue them together. Sounds like you took a similar approach using buttons.

Another option might be to use one of the jQuery image libraries within the webview. This most likely will have a performance penalty though.